# SQL mobile number validation

Tags: sql-server, validation, mobile

I have my sql database where i would like to filter out all the valid mobile numbers.

I currently use as follows;

```
WHERE pn.PhoneNumber LIKE '+[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR pn.PhoneNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR pn.PhoneNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR pn.PhoneNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

However I still receive numbers such as `0000000`, `0` ,`0000` etc.
Some of the numbers aren't Irish mobiles either as they don't begin with `08`.
To fix there if I wanted the beginning of the number to begin with an `087` would I just input `[0][8][7]` instead of the `[0-9]`?

Comment: if every mobile number begins with 087 then you use `087%` then put your other validations!

Comment: so like this '087% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'

Comment: nope that'd still have nos like this 0879999999 ! can you give saome examples which you consider as valid and invalid?

Comment: a valid number would begin with 087 and can have an array of numbers after, the total length is 10 digits including the 087 part an invalid number would be 0000000000 or 0891234567 or 0184521598. The beginning of the number must be 087 but the remaining 7 digits can be any combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try testing this !

this'll give numbers starting with `087` and `mobile(length)=10`

```
select * from table where mobile_number like '087%' and LEN(mobile_number)=10
```

### <kbd>[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15699)</kbd>

Comment: tested that and it still includes a number starting with 002?

Comment: Thanks that works however I tried to do the same for 003538%' and LEN(Customer.MobilePhone) = 14 but is doesn't seem to be picking it up?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table containing all the prefixes that I was interested in and then use that to do the validation.

Something like ....

```
Create table Allowed ( Prefix VARCHAR(10) )

insert into allowed values ( '071' );
insert into allowed values ( '072' );
insert into allowed values ( '+44' );

select count(prefix) as OK
from allowed
where REPLACE( pn.phonenumber, ' ', '') like prefix || '%'
```

You can still do the numeric validation separately, or combine the regexp part into the suffix added above.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is out of date but just developed code for a UK Mobile Number that someone might find useful. It checks with or without a space, hyphen etc after the first 5 numbers and returns a blank if the number isn't valid - I need to upload records to a third party who reject records with invalid mobile numbers but accept blanks.

```
Mobile = CASE WHEN MobileTel LIKE '07[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' THEN left(MobileTel,11) WHEN MobileTel LIKE '07[0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' THEN  (LEFT(MobileTel,5)+substring(MobileTel,7,6)) ELSE '' END
```